# Python: How to get the left or top in pyautogui.locateOnScreen as int?

Tags: python, automation, bots, pyautogui

How can I get the left, top, width and heigth as an int value instead of the standard 'Box(left, top, width, height)'. I need these values to make if statements like: "if left < 250".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Update:

You can just use x[0] for the left, x[1] for the top etc.

NOTE: this doesn't work when x="None". use 'try' to prevent the code from crashing when trying to call x[something].